# passing parameters in ajax with jquery from input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

Once I add the date and time the url should like this become

```
http://metrobikes.in/api/cities/1/models?start_time=14%3A00&end_time=16%3A00&end_date=2017-10-27&start_date=2017-10-27
```

I.e. it should load the bikes available at that time

```js
$('#btn-bik-sel').on('click', function() {
  alert("asdada");
  alert($('#datetimepicker2').val());
});


function available() {
  var date = $('#datetimepicker2').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://metrobikes.in/api/cities/1/models?',
    method: "GET",
    data: {
      'start_time': start_time,
      'end_time': end_time,
      'end_date': end_date,
      'start_date': start_date
    },
  }).done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.result.data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data);
    };
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" id="datetimepicker2" placeholder="Start date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="Start time" style="margin-top: 10px">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" id="datetimepicker21" placeholder="End date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control date-time" id="datetimepicker111" placeholder="End time" style="margin-top: 10px">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-bik-sel">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `start_time`, `end_time` etc...?

Comment: its an input field where user can enter any start and end date and time

Comment: Yes, but where are you setting those JS variables? They don't magically set the values without you writing some code to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your `data` section to this:

```
...
data: {
      'start_time': $('#datetimepicker1').val(),
      'end_time': $('#datetimepicker111').val(),
      'end_date': $('#datetimepicker21').val(),
      'start_date': $('#datetimepicker2').val()
    },
```

Comment: and after that? if i click the button ill get the desired result?.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting values to `start_time`, `end_time`, `start_date` and `end_date`. They don't magically set the values without you writing some code to do it. You can get those values using

**`$('#your-id').val();`**

Comment: If this answer is useful please accept my answer @Syed Tabeeb